# Rails, Gon - You can't use Gon public methods for storing data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, gon

I have following error when try login in app:

```
You can't use Gon public methods for storing data
```

Pointed to this code:

```
gon.current_user = { sn: current_user.sn }
```

Can you help me what is wrong with this code?
I am using version 5.2.3 of Gon.

Comment: Are you using any reserved word by any chance?

Comment: https://github.com/gazay/gon/blob/master/lib/gon.rb#L39

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by redefining: gon.env = Rails.env to gon.enviro = Rails.env

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with the gon.

After some investigation, I was able to find that I was using gon ~> 5.2.0 in Gemfile, and when I updated the gems it got updated to 5.2.3.

I think in 5.2.3 the current_user was added to public methods list.

So I changed the gon ~> 5.2.0 to gon 5.2.0, and rebundled and the issue was gone.